# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyimagesearch'

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to do four-point image transformation and I need to import this library.

I am getting this error

```
>>> from pyimagesearch.transform import four_point_transform
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyimagesearch'
```

[image: Error Code image]

I have installed cv2 by pip but still getting this error.

Comment: Assuming you used the stuff from [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/): _I decided put it in the `pyimagesearch` sub-module for organizational purposes._ So, maybe download the whole source code from there and follow possible instructions provided? This is not OpenCV-related, thus I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function instead of module:

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import cv2

def order_points(pts):
    # initialzie a list of coordinates that will be ordered
    # such that the first entry in the list is the top-left,
    # the second entry is the top-right, the third is the
    # bottom-right, and the fourth is the bottom-left
    rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype = "float32")

    # the top-left point will have the smallest sum, whereas
    # the bottom-right point will have the largest sum
    s = pts.sum(axis = 1)
    rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
    rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]

    # now, compute the difference between the points, the
    # top-right point will have the smallest difference,
    # whereas the bottom-left will have the largest difference
    diff = np.diff(pts, axis = 1)
    rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
    rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]

    # return the ordered coordinates
    return rect
```

And

```
def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    # obtain a consistent order of the points and unpack them
    # individually
    rect = order_points(pts)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect

    # compute the width of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between bottom-right and bottom-left
    # x-coordiates or the top-right and top-left x-coordinates
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))

    # compute the height of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between the top-right and bottom-right
    # y-coordinates or the top-left and bottom-left y-coordinates
    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))

    # now that we have the dimensions of the new image, construct
    # the set of destination points to obtain a "birds eye view",
    # (i.e. top-down view) of the image, again specifying points
    # in the top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
    # order
    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
        [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # compute the perspective transform matrix and then apply it
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))

    # return the warped image
    return warped
```

As mentioned above, this is not part of Open-CV.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function instead of module:

```
def four_point_transform(image, pts):
# obtain a consistent order of the points and unpack them
# individually
rect = order_points(pts)
(tl, tr, br, bl) = rect

# compute the width of the new image, which will be the
# maximum distance between bottom-right and bottom-left
# x-coordiates or the top-right and top-left x-coordinates
widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))

# compute the height of the new image, which will be the
# maximum distance between the top-right and bottom-right
# y-coordinates or the top-left and bottom-left y-coordinates
heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))

# now that we have the dimensions of the new image, construct
# the set of destination points to obtain a "birds eye view",
# (i.e. top-down view) of the image, again specifying points
# in the top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
# order
dst = np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [maxWidth - 1, 0],
    [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
    [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")

# compute the perspective transform matrix and then apply it
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))

# return the warped image
return warped
```

This is not part of Open-CV.

Comment: says: "NameError: name 'order_points' is not defined", is that another lib import?

Answer (score 0):

since `pyimagesearch` is a package(folder), so u can't `pip install` it.
the solution is to copy `pyimagesearch` folder to (site-packages) : `\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages`

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
sudo pip3 install pyimagesearch
sudo apt-get install python3-pyimagesearch
```

Comment: `pyimagesearch` is not any usual `pip` module. It is just the folder name containing the project.